# Invoke class method with custom parameters using google mock

Tags: unit-testing, invoke, googletest, googlemock

I'm developing some unit tests on a serial application in c++ using google mock framework.

The mock I've built for my serial port interface is:

```
class MockSerialPort: public SerialPortInterface {
public:
MOCK_METHOD0(Open, void());
MOCK_METHOD0(IsOpen,bool());
MOCK_METHOD4(Configure,void(int,int,int,SerialParity));
MOCK_METHOD0(Close,void());
MOCK_METHOD0(Read,queue<char>());
MOCK_METHOD1(RegisterSerialObserver,void(SerialObserver*));
MOCK_METHOD0(NotifySerialObserver,void());
MOCK_METHOD0(Die, void());
virtual ~MockSerialPort() {Die(); }
};
```

The  implementation of NotifySerialObserver in my real implementation is:

```
void UnixSerialPort::NotifySerialObserver(){
this->serialManager->HandleSerialEvent(this->portID);
 }
```

And the test I'm using is:

```
TEST(SerialPortManagerTest,PortReadThrowsExceptionOnReadError){
PortID portID=COM1;

MockSerialPort* port1=new MockSerialPort();
EXPECT_CALL(*port1, Read()).Times(Exactly(1)).WillOnce(Throw(SerialPortReadErrorException()));

MockSerialPort* port2=new MockSerialPort();
MockSerialPort* port3=new MockSerialPort();

MockSerialPortFactory portFactory;
EXPECT_CALL(portFactory, CreateSerialPort(_)).Times(3).
        WillOnce(ReturnPointee(&port1)).
        WillOnce(ReturnPointee(&port2)).
        WillOnce(ReturnPointee(&port3));

SerialPortManager* serialPortManager =new SerialPortManager((SerialPortFactoryInterface*)&portFactory);

 <<<Need to add EXPECT_CALL on *port1->NotifySerialObserver() that invokes serialPortManager->HandleSerialEvent(COM1)>>>>

serialPortManager->OpenPort(portID);
EXPECT_THROW(port1->NotifySerialObserver(),SerialPortReadErrorException);

delete serialPortManager;
}
```

I need to test that when port1->NotifySerialObserver() is called serialPortManager reads from port1. Is there a way of invoke serialPortManager->HandleSerialEvent(COM1) from the mocked serial port?

**EDIT** This is the serialPortManager constructor

```
SerialPortManager::SerialPortManager(
        SerialPortFactoryInterface* serialPortFactory,SerialParserInterface* serialParser) {
    this->serialPortFactory = serialPortFactory;
    this->serialParser=serialParser;
    for (int i = 0; i < PORT_COUNT; i++) {
        ports[i] = serialPortFactory->CreateSerialPort((PortID) i);
        cout << "Created port " << i << endl;
        ports[i]->RegisterSerialObserver(this);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to restructure your test to ensure that the `SerialPortManager` and `MockSerialPortFactory` are created in `SetUp()` and destroyed in `TearDown()`.  You'll also need a member function to call `HandleSerialEvent` with the correct arguments on `SerialPortManager`:

```
class SerialPortManager : public Test
{
    MockSerialPortFactory* portFactory;
    SerialPortManager* serialPortManager;

protected:
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
        portFactory = new MockSerialPortFactory();
        serialPortManager = new SerialPortManager(portFactory);
    }

    virtual void TearDown()
    {
        delete serialPortManager;
        delete portFactory;
    }

    void handleCOM1SerialEvent()
    {
        serialPortManager->HandleSerialEvent(COM1);
    }
};
```

Then your test can invoke the member function on a call to the mock serial port:

```
TEST(SerialPortManagerTest,PortReadThrowsExceptionOnReadError){
PortID portID=COM1;

MockSerialPort* port1=new MockSerialPort();
EXPECT_CALL(*port1, Read()).Times(Exactly(1)).WillOnce(Throw(SerialPortReadErrorException()));

MockSerialPort* port2=new MockSerialPort();
MockSerialPort* port3=new MockSerialPort();

EXPECT_CALL(*portFactory, CreateSerialPort(_)).Times(3).
        WillOnce(Return(port1)).
        WillOnce(Return(port2)).
        WillOnce(Return(port3));

EXPECT_CALL(*port1, NotifySerialObserver()).
        WillOnce(Invoke(this, &SerialPortManagerTest::handleCOM1SerialEvent));

serialPortManager->OpenPort(portID);

}
```

Note that I'm not sure from your code where `CreateSerialPort` is called inside `SerialPortManager`.  If it's called inside the constructor for `SerialPortManager`, then you'll also have to move the `MockSerialPort` construction and destruction to `SetUp()` and `TearDown()`, respectively.

**Update**
Here's a suggested implementation given that `CreateSerialPort` is called inside `SerialPortManager`.  I've used [`NiceMock`](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#The_Nice,_the_Strict,_and_the_Naggy) to get rid of the uninteresting mock function call warnings.  I've also left the `MockSerialPort` construction inside the test body for simplicity.  Essentially you have to ensure that the `EXPECT_CALL` for `CreateSerialPort` occurs before the `SerialPortManager` is constructed:

```
class SerialPortManager : public Test
{
    MockSerialPortFactory* portFactory;
    SerialPortManager* serialPortManager;

protected:
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
        portFactory = new NiceMock<MockSerialPortFactory>();
        serialPortManager = nullptr;  // Use NULL if not using C++11.
    }

    virtual void TearDown()
    {
        delete serialPortManager;
        delete portFactory;
    }

    void createSerialPortManager()
    {
        serialPortManager = new SerialPortManager(portFactory);
    }

    void handleCOM1SerialEvent()
    {
        serialPortManager->HandleSerialEvent(COM1);
    }
};

TEST(SerialPortManagerTest,PortReadThrowsExceptionOnReadError){
PortID portID=COM1;

MockSerialPort* port1=new MockSerialPort();
EXPECT_CALL(*port1, Read())
    .Times(Exactly(1)).WillOnce(Throw(SerialPortReadErrorException()));

MockSerialPort* port2=new MockSerialPort();
MockSerialPort* port3=new MockSerialPort();

EXPECT_CALL(*portFactory, CreateSerialPort(_)).Times(3).
        WillOnce(Return(port1)).
        WillOnce(Return(port2)).
        WillOnce(Return(port3));

createSerialPortManager();

EXPECT_CALL(*port1, NotifySerialObserver()).
        WillOnce(Invoke(this, &SerialPortManagerTest::handleCOM1SerialEvent));

serialPortManager->OpenPort(portID);

}
```

Comment: In fact, CreateSerialPort is called inside SerialPortManager constructor. I used the suggested test fixture including the MockSerialPort construction in the SetUp(). But I'm getting segmentation fault in the test on the first call to CreateSerialPort.

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: CreateSerialPort(0)
          Returns: NULL
Stack trace:
Created port 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)